# Combine gdal tiles into large tif

Tags: python, gdal

I'm currently using gdal2tiles.py to tile a large TIF, then I do post-processing on each of these tiles.  Does gdal have a utility I can use to stitch these tiles back in place to recreate a large TIF.  I understand that I may lose some quality here by doing so but that is fine.  If gdal doesn't have anything for this are there any other tools that do?  Thanks.

**Update:  Using gdal_mergy.py**

using this code

```
python gdal_merge.py -o mos.tif -of GTiff -v --optfile tif_list.txt
```

It seems like they are always being copied over each other at 0,0,256,256.  Output from gdal_merge:

[image: output]

Comment: See [gdal_merge.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_merge.html)

Comment: @MikeT thanks Mike,  this seems like what I want but when I create the mosaic it is always 256x256 and only displays the last .png it processed.  here is the command I'm using, python gdal_merge.py -o mos.tif -of GTiff -v --optfile tif_list.txt

Comment: Are the input files properly referenced? It seems that all of them have their origin at (0,0) You may add a World File https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=World_file which is an ascii file with a proper extension (.pgw) describing the coordinates of each file.